Интеграция Telegram бота с Jivo через Webhook
Я занимаюсь интеграцией Telegram бота с платформой Jivo через Webhook, и столкнулся с несколькими проблемами. Мне нужно помочь с правильной настройкой и тестированием этой интеграции. Вот что я уже сделал и какие вопросы у меня возникли:
Настройка Webhook в Telegram:
Я использовал команду для установки Webhook через URL моего сервера на Heroku. Запрос прошёл успешно, и я получил ответ { "ok": true, "result": true, "description": "Webhook is already set" }. Но когда я тестирую, сообщения от бота не отображаются в чате Jivo.
Как правильно тестировать Webhook, и что может быть причиной того, что сообщения не доходят до Jivo?
Удаление Webhook:
Мне пришлось удалить Webhook через deleteWebhook команду, чтобы заново настроить его. Всё прошло успешно, но при попытке повторного запуска бота я получаю ошибку telegram.error.Conflict: can't use getUpdates method while webhook is active; use deleteWebhook to delete the webhook first.
Как правильно управлять Webhook и что нужно сделать, чтобы устранить эту ошибку?
Использование токена бота в коде:
Я храню токен бота прямо в коде для отправки сообщений и обработки Webhook запросов. Но это небезопасно, и я хотел бы использовать переменные окружения для токенов.
Как лучше передавать токен бота и URL для Webhook через переменные окружения, чтобы не хранить их прямо в коде?
Проблемы с Jivo:
После интеграции Telegram бота с Jivo, сообщения вроде команды /start попадают в чат Jivo, но не обрабатываются должным образом.
Как правильно интегрировать бота с Jivo, чтобы сообщения корректно обрабатывались?
Дополнительная информация:
Я использую Flask для развертывания приложения на Heroku и библиотеку python-telegram-bot для работы с ботом.
Вот часть кода, который я использую:
# Пример Flask и Telegram бота с Webhook
@app.route('/telegram-webhook', methods=['POST'])
async def telegram_webhook():
    update = Update.de_json(request.get_json(), telegram_app.bot)
    await telegram_app.process_update(update)
    return jsonify({'status': 'ok'})


Любая помощь или советы будут очень полезны!
Основные вопросы, которые я задавал:
Как настроить и тестировать Webhook в Telegram?
Как удалить Webhook и решить проблему с конфликтом getUpdates?
Как хранить токен бота и Webhook URL через переменные окружения на Heroku?
Как правильно интегрировать Telegram бота с Jivo, чтобы сообщения корректно обрабатывались?
